# Doubt regarding a famous question of linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, direct-sum

There is a famous question from the book on Linear Algebra by Friedberg which says:

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space, and let $T: V → V$ be linear.
Prove that $V = R(T^k) \oplus N(T^k)$ for some positive integer $k$.

**My answer :**

I first observed that for $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$R(T^{n+1}) = T^{n+1}(V) = T^n(T(V)) = T^n(R(T)) \subseteq T^n(V) = R(T^n)$$
So, $R(T^{n+1}) \subseteq R(T^n) \ \ \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N}$ and hence  $rank(T) \geq rank(T^2) \geq rank(T^3) \geq \cdots$.

So, as rank of a transformation must be a natural number, this implies that

$\exists \ \ k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\  rank(T^m) = rank(T^k) \ \  \forall \ \ m \geq k$

$\implies rank (T^k) = rank(T^{2k})$.

Now we know:

- for $U : X \to Y$,  $rank (U) = rank(U^{2}) \implies X = R(U) \oplus N(U)$
- and $T^k : R(T^{k-1}) \to V$

Hence, we get : $R(T^{k-1}) = R(T^k) \oplus N(T^k)$

**My doubt :**

What am I missing here ? How am I supposed to get $V = R(T^k) \oplus N(T^k)$ ?

**P.S.   Doubt cleared :**

See the discussion in the comment box.

Comment: Why $T^k : R(T^{k-1}) \to V$ and not $T^k : V \to V$?

Comment: We have $T: V \to V$ not necessarily onto. Hence, $T^2 : R(T) \to V $... and so on.

Comment: But $T^2$ (and $T^k$) is still defined for all of $V$. Consider $T= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Then $T^2 = T$, $T: V \to V$ so $T^2 : V\to V$ but  $R(T) = \{(x,0)\}_x \subset V$. Or in words $T^k$ is the map that applies $T$ $k$ times to any $v$ in the domain of $T$, the domain of $T$ is $V$ by definition and so the domain of $T^k$ is also $V$.

Comment: Wow! I don't know how I missed that. Thanks a lot for clearing my stupid doubt.